# comparing transcendence degrees of field of fractions and residue fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A,B$ be integral domains such that $A \subset B$, $P$ a prime ideal of $B$ and $p$ its contraction in $A$. Let $K_A, K_B$ be the field of fractions of $A,B$ respectively and let $\kappa(p), \kappa(P)$ be the residue fields.

Question 1: what is the relation between $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{\kappa(p)} \kappa(P)$ and $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{K_A} K_B$? Can we compare these two degrees maybe in some important cases?

Question 2: What is (if any) the geometric significance of $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{\kappa(p)} \kappa(P)$ and $\operatorname{tr.deg}_{K_A} K_B$?

Motivation: Matsumura's Theorem 15.5 (Commutative Ring Theory)